# Python Folium expected to values for location

Tags: python, folium

I was trying to create a program that traces ip adresses and plots them on a map but got the error:
ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: [].
i am using notepad to create the file and cmd to run it.

```
import geocoder
import folium

ip = input('Enter IP to trace: ')
g = geocoder.ip(ip)
location = g.latlng


locationmap1 = folium.Map(location=location, zoom_start=12)

folium.CircleMarker(location=location, radius=50).add_to(locationmap1)
locationmap1.save('locationmap1.html')
locationmap1.show_in_browser()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet runs.  The bug you are running into is because when you run `geocoder.id` on an invalid IP, g.latlng returns an empty array. My suggestion would be to check that once the `location` is available, ensure that it is valid by checking that it is valid.

```js
import geocoder
import folium

ip = "12.215.42.19"
g = geocoder.ip(ip)
location = g.latlng

print(location) // [32.7831, -96.8067]

locationmap1 = folium.Map(location=location, zoom_start=12)

folium.CircleMarker(location=location, radius=50).add_to(locationmap1)
```

Comment: For some reason, the map is coming up empty, do you know why it might?

Comment: my guess would be if the location was not valid